# Excel VBA sumifs sort and set

Tags: vba, excel

I need some help in this query.

So I have this data:

```
|  A    |    B    |    C   |   D  |
----------------------------------
Date       int001   int002  int003
2/1/2016     10       11      12
2/2/2016     5        5      -5
2/3/2016    -4       -4       4
2/4/2016     5        5      -5
2/1/2016     2       -2       2
2/2/2016    -3       -2      -1
2/3/2016     1        1       1
2/4/2016     2       -1       3
2/1/2016    -4       -5       6
2/2/2016    -2       -2       2
2/3/2016    -1        1      -1
2/4/2016    -5       -3       1
```

With this data i need to calculate a sum based on unique dates and pozitive values.

For first unique_date i need:

- sum of column B where the values > 0 and set in H2
- sum of column C where the values > 0 and set in H3
- sum of column D where the values > 0 and set in H4

For second unique_date i need:

- sum of column B where the values > 0 and set in H5
- sum of column C where the values > 0 and set in H6
- sum of column D where the values > 0 and set in H7

For third unique_date i need:

- sum of column B where the values > 0 and set in H8
- sum of column C where the values > 0 and set in H9
- sum of column D where the values > 0 and set in H10

For forth unique_date i need:

- sum of column B where the values > 0 and set in H11
- sum of column C where the values > 0 and set in H12
- sum of column D where the values > 0 and set in H13

The column "F" with unique data from column "A" is work.
But the column "H", still doesn't work.

The results i need is:

```
|   F     |    H    |
---------------------
Uniq Dates   Results:
2/1/2016     12
2/2/2016     11
2/3/2016     20
2/4/2016     5
             5
             2
             1
             2
             5
             7
             5
             4
```

This is the code which i write:

```
Sub Tsum()

Dim int001 As Range
Dim int002 As Range
Dim int003 As Range
Dim data1 As Date
Dim data2 As Date
Dim data3 As Date
Dim nr_rows As Integer 
Dim dates As Range 
Dim nr_unique_dates As Integer 
Dim unique_dates As Range 

'--------------------------------------------------------------
nr_rows = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 
Set int001 = Range("B2:B" & nr_rows)
Set int002 = Range("C2:C" & nr_rows)
Set int003 = Range("D2:D" & nr_rows)
Set dates = Range("A2:A" & nr_rows) 
'--------------------------------------------------------------
Range("A1:A" & nr_rows).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy,         CopyToRange:=Range("F1"), Unique:=True
nr_unique_dates = Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row  
Set unique_dates = Range("F2:F" & nr_unique_dates) 

Range("H2:H" & nr_rows) = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(dates, int001, int002, int003, unique_dates, int001, int002, int003, ">0")

End Sub
```

---- The problem is somewhere bellow, because i don't know how to loop it

```
Range("H2:H" & nr_rows) = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(dates, int001, int002, int003, unique_dates, int001, int002, int003, ">0")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**edited** after OP clarifications:

substitute:

```
Range("H2:H" & nr_rows) = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(dates, int001, int002, int003, unique_dates, int001, int002, int003, ">0")
```

with:

```
    Dim iDate As Long
    With Range("H1")
        For iDate = 1 To nr_unique_dates - 1
        .Offset((iDate - 1) * 3 + 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(int001, dates, unique_dates(iDate), int001, ">0")
        .Offset((iDate - 1) * 3 + 2) = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(int002, dates, unique_dates(iDate), int002, ">0")
        .Offset((iDate - 1) * 3 + 3) = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(int003, dates, unique_dates(iDate), int003, ">0")
        Next iDate
    End With
```

Comment: Thank you and sorry for my initial explanation. I edit the post with the correct info. Your code makes the sum for columns(B+C+D), and i want separately. Can you help me with that?

Comment: When i introduce another date (2/4/2016) with values for int001, int002 and int003, the results shifted with 1 space, wich is empty or 0. How can i solve this issue ?

Comment: see edited post. I was offsetting rows by a value connected to both `iDate` and `nr_unique_dates` (e.g: `(iDate - 1) * (nr_unique_dates - 1) + 1`) while it should only be connected to `iDate`, being the set of cells always be a multiple of 3 (i.e. the number of data columns to sum over)

Comment: If I add anothor values in columns "E, F" (int004, int005...) the  code works?

Comment: No, it has to be updated: basically you have to 1) add `Set int00X = Range("..2:.." & nr_rows)` statements  before the `For iDate = 1` loop 2) add `.Offset((iDate - 1) * 3 + 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(int00X, dates, unique_dates(iDate), int00X, ">0")` statements inside `For iDate = 1 ...` loop for every new _int00X_

Comment: I understand that. In my case i have "int001" "int002"..... "int024" and 29 unique dates. Here:     `.Offset((iDate - 1) * 24 + 1) = `...24 times....    `Offset((iDate - 1) * 24 + 24) = `....He calculate but not all the results is good

Comment: In this case I'd have a code refactoring to loop through data columns, too. Should you have problems you may post a new question with your code attemps

Comment: in your new post you must add at least a link to this one in order for people to understand what's what