# Excel VBA offset

Tags: vba

Initial question: [Excel VBA sumifs sort and set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39072597/excel-vba-sumifs-sort-and-set/39073233)

So i have :

int001, int001, .....int024

and  29 unique_data.

I think here i'am doing something wrong:

```
) * 24 + 1) ...24 times....* 24 + 24)
```

but i don't know what.

```
Dim iDate As Long
    With Range("C1")
    For iDate = 1 To nr_unique_dates - 1
        .Offset((iDate - 1) * 24 + 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(INT001, dates, unique_dates(iDate), INT001, ">0")
        .Offset((iDate - 1) * 24 + 2) = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(INT002, dates, unique_dates(iDate), INT002, ">0")

                                      |     

                                      |

                                      |

                                      |

        .Offset((iDate - 1) * 24 + 22) = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(INT022, dates, unique_dates(iDate), INT022, ">0")
        .Offset((iDate - 1) * 24 + 23) = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(INT023, dates, unique_dates(iDate), INT023, ">0")
        .Offset((iDate - 1) * 24 + 24) = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(INT024, dates, unique_dates(iDate), INT024, ">0")




    Next iDate
```

Comment: Can you please be more clear? Whats wrong with your code? Any errors? Whats not working ?

Comment: "int001, int001, .....int024"?  Are you familiar with arrays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**edited** after OP request about output zeros

**edited2** after OP clarifications about output zeros

If the rest of your code stays the same as in the linked one, then you're messing things up with `With Range("C1")` instead of the *original*  `With Range("H1")`, since C1 is right inside your *intXXX* data

Since 24 columns of *intXXX* range from column "B" to column "Y" you should use `With Range("Z1")` (or, to stay two columns away from data, `With Range("AA1")`)

You should be done with such a modification but I'd suggest you to follow @JohnColeman piece of advice about an "array approach"

Here follows a "range approach" for an *open* number of *intXXX*:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Tsum2()
    Dim unique_dates As Range, outputRng As Range
    Dim nr_unique_dates As Long
    Dim iDate As Long, nr_Cols As Long, iCol As Long

    With Worksheets("TSums") '<-- change "TSums" with your actual sheet name
        Set outputRng = Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(, 2) '<--| set output range as tow columns right of the last non empty cell in row 1
        With .Range("G1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)) '<-- reference the range from cell "A1" to cell in column "G" corresponding to last non empty row in column "A"
            nr_Cols = .Columns.Count '<--| store data columns
            .Columns(1).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=outputRng, Unique:=True '<-- call AdvancedFilter on first column of the referenced range
            Set unique_dates = Range(outputRng.Offset(1), outputRng.End(xlDown)) '<--| set unique dates range
            nr_unique_dates = unique_dates.Count '<--| store unique dates number
            With .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1) '<--| skip headers of reference range
                For iDate = 1 To nr_unique_dates '<--| outer loop through unique dates
                    For iCol = 2 To nr_Cols '<--| inner loop through "int" columns (from column 2 rightwards)
                        outputRng.Offset((iDate - 1) * (nr_Cols - 1) + iCol - 1, 2) = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(.Columns(iCol), .Columns(1), unique_dates(iDate), .Columns(iCol), ">0")
                    Next iCol
                Next iDate
            End With
        End With
    End With
    With outputRng.Offset(, 2)
        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Replace 0, ""    '<--| substitute all output "zeros" with a blank value
        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Delete   '<--| delete all blanks
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @Marius: did you get through it?

Comment: Thank you, It works. But when i have in a column only negatives values the sum is set with value 0 and in this case i don't need any values to set.

Comment: `2/1/2016`    `10  6    4`  <br/>  
   `2/2/2016`  `-5    3    2`  <br/>
    `2/3/2016`   `3    7    3`  <br/>
   `2/1/2016`   `1    2    5`  <br/>
   `2/2/2016`  `-4    3    7`  <br/>
    `2/3/2016`   `6    4    2`     <br/> 
Like in this case when in column int 1 with date 2/2/2016 have only negatives

Comment: I don't want space beetween sum of positive values, i want a continuation with positive sums. Can you put an if to jump the algoritm when i have negative values in that column ?

Comment: When i have the sum <=0 in a specific date, don't calculate or set the sum

Comment: Or to use the last code, and to create another "results column" where can put a condition that where find a 0 in the old "results column", scroll down and take the next values >0 and put in that place where was the 0.

Comment: see edited answer. but without any effort on your part you'll never go ahead